# Android phone very slow to connect to Ubuntu 18.04 using USB

Tags: usb, 18.04, android

My android phone (Samsung C9 Pro, Android 8.0.0) takes several minutes to connect to Ubuntu 18.04. As soon as I plug USB cable in, it is immediately detected. But clicking on the device in Nautilus just results in not being able to connect. If I just leave it for several minutes it eventually connects.
No problem connecting with 16.04, Xubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu Mate 18.04 etc. Strangely, there is also no problem connecting if I install Unity desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 and switch to the Unity environment.

Comment: I too am very interested in a solution to this ... issue like this is what is holding back adoption of ubuntu ... please update to mention which version of android

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that the root of the problem is probably Gnome, although I have no hard evidence! I don't have this problem with any other distros. I am back to 16.04 until this problem gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar problem: I can connect to the phone, but when I navigate to the DCIM folder, and try to open 'Camera', that's when it hangs for a couple of minutes.

It turns out that for me, the problem was caused by (a bug in Ubuntu triggered by) a filename which contained parentheses.  (Probably an opening parenthesis only.)

So, the solution is to use the file manager on the phone, or the ubuntu file manager after waiting for however long it takes to connect, find the filename with the parentheses, and rename it to something without parentheses.

If some software relies on the filename containing parentheses, too bad for that software.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1792085